# Is there an umbrella word for "Installment" "Lender" "Financier" and "Investor"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

I have multiple category of clients:

- **Installment payment provider**
- Startup/Project **Financier** or **Investor**
- Money **lender**

I am looking for an umbrella word suitable to substitute the above in general.

Comment: Is 'investors' too broad?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can I call a lender as "investor"?

Comment: And why not ***client***?

Comment: It depends on the contract involved. In business, almost certainly – a loan made at an agreed rate of interest, with a certain amount of risk being involved.

Comment: @Jim I have other clients which are the "beneficiaries". I use beneficiary as the umbrella word for clients who benefit from "Installment payment provider", "Investor" and "Lender". You see, two categories for clients and on each category I have other categories that why I want an umbrella for the mentioned sub-categories. I call them "Providers" but I am looking for a better word than "provider".

Comment: An installment payment provider sounds like someone who makes payments on an installment loan.

Comment: What they all have in common is owning a financial security; is "security holder" too made up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like these entities are all **[creditors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creditor)** in your situation, as opposed to the other clients who are **debtors**.

Answer (score 0):

They are all ***economic actors***  [The Free Dictionary](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Economic+Actors) says an *economic actor* is:

> A person or unit able to use land, labor or capital. An economic actor
>   uses these resources to shape an economy, usually (though not always)
>   for his own benefit. An economic actor may be an individual, a
>   company, a government or even a society as a whole.